# mysql query -not getting the result it should provide

Tags: mysql, sql

```
    SELECT ex.`ID`, ex.`ExpenseName`, om.`Taka`, SUM( om.`Taka` ) AS 'Total Taka' 
    FROM (office_expense_main om) 
        JOIN (office_expenses ex) 
               ON (ex.ID=om.OfficeExpenseID) 
        JOIN (yyyy_mm_officeexpense ym) 
               ON ( ym.Year_Month = '" + _yearMonth + "' AND om.YearMonthID <= ym.ID ) 
    GROUP BY om.`OfficeExpenseID`
```

This query should show [om.`Taka`] of given [ym.Year_Month] and sum[om.`Taka`] - that the sum of all previous Taka till the given Year_Month. Group By om.ID

Now, it showing 'Taka' of the first Year_Month (eg. if i want to see 'taka' of march and sum('Taka') till march, it's showing me 'Taka' of january (the first entry in yyyy_mm table) NOT for march. but showing the sum('Taka') exactly what i want to see) not the one I provided. but sum(Taka) till the given YearMonth.!

But it shows exactly same result before yesterday! but I didnt change anything in this and i am not getting why its showing different NOW..

Can anybody help me!

Comment: if you still have issues, do you mind updating your question with some sample table data and your expected results pleaes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is failing because of a (mis)feature in MySQL called Hidden Columns.  The column name om.Taka is not an aggregation column, so MySQL returns an arbitrary value.  Well, usually it is the first value as you see, but this is not guaranteed.

You need to join back to the office_expense_main table.  I think the following may be what you want:

```
SELECT ex.id, ex.`ExpenseName`, omlatest.om.taka, SUM( om.`Taka` ) AS 'Total Taka' 
FROM office_expense_main om JOIN
     office_expenses ex
     ON ex.ID = om.OfficeExpenseID JOIN
     yyyy_mm_officeexpense ym
     ON ym.Year_Month = '" + _yearMonth + "' AND om.YearMonthID <= ym.ID join
     office_expenses omlatest
     on om.YearMonthId = ym.id and exiID = omlatest.OfficeExpenseId
GROUP BY ex.id
```

I haven't tested this query, so it might have syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this SQL will compile.  Look at your `GROUP BY` statement, you should `GROUP BY` the fields you are selecting:

```
GROUP BY ex.ID, ex.ExpenseName , om.Taka
```

Also, I don't think you are intending to be using the SUM operator and the GROUP BY operator on the same field.  Not sure what else might be going on.

Comment: ex.ID and om.OfficeExpenseID are the same just primary and foreign key of two different tables.

Comment: This query is showing exactly what it should if i change [om.YearMonthID <= ym.ID] to [om.YearMonthID >= ym.ID] ..

Comment: The syntax is valid in MySQL.  It is a (mis) feature called Hidden Columns.

Comment: +1 Thanks @GordonLinoff - very much appreciated for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Your query will get different results when you run it because your select field (`om.taka`) is a field that's used in the group function (`sum(om.taka)`).  This is what I mean.  Let say you have this:

```
mysql> select * from foo;
+------+------+
| a    | b    |
+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |
|    1 |    3 |
+------+------+
```

if you do a select using a field that is in the group function, you can get this:

depending on how mysql decided on which order of the order of the rows.  To be specific, see this:

```
mysql> select a, b, sum(b) from foo group by a;
+------+------+--------+
| a    | b    | sum(b) |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    2 |      5 |
+------+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

But that is because of the order in which the rows were processed.  If the order was reversed, then you would get a different result.

```
mysql> select a, b, sum(b) from (select * from foo order by b asc) t group by a;
+------+------+--------+
| a    | b    | sum(b) |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    2 |      5 |
+------+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select a, b, sum(b) from (select * from foo order by b desc) t group by a;
+------+------+--------+
| a    | b    | sum(b) |
+------+------+--------+
|    1 |    3 |      5 |
+------+------+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

The lesson is if you are selecting a field that you're using in the group function, you're going to get arbitrary results.